# accessing Object[] values in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

Regarding to this image: [link text](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?4ad8c1c1dd.jpg)

I have an object, 'rezultat', which has getters and setters. I wanna set for 'cli' attribute ( `rezultat.setCli(String .....)` ), and as string parameter it should be that `m_objArray[0]`, so 'ADSL22675....' from that image. Expanding `m_objArray` there are 19 attributes i need to set for the 'rezultat' object attributes. But i don't know how to access them.

```
Array o = ocs.getArray(1);
Object[] obj = (Object[])o.getArray();
rezultat = new ListOfMdfTab();
for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
rezultat.setCli ((String)obj[0].<what>?); //i need here that m_objArray[0].
}
```

'ocs' is an OracleCallableStatament object type, so i need  `Array o = ocs.getArray(1);`  because that 1 index is the out parameter which is a complx type.
Please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STRUCT` is an oracle class that implements the `java.sql.Struct` interface. This interface offers a `getAttributes()` method.

It's worth a try calling this method and hoping for the best, that the array that is returned is equal to the internal `m_objArray`.

In Java code:

```
rezultat.setCli(((java.sql.Struct)obj[0]).getAttributes()[0].toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

This statement will return a String or will throw a clasCastException if the Object is not a string:

```
(String)obj[0]
```

If you're not sure if it is a String you could use

```
obj[0].toString()
```

OR

```
String.valueOf(obj[0])
```

Which will handle nulls more elegantly

Comment: From the picture OP linked, `obj[0]` is a `STRUCT` (whatever that means). Within it there's a `Object[] m_objArray` which contains `String`. At least that's how I'm reading it.

Comment: I tried with obj[0].toString() and it returned oracle.sql.STRUCT. So, the type. I need the values from m_objArray, that node contains 19 elements, whose values i need (see that image).

Comment: Yes, true: rom the picture OP linked, obj[0] is a STRUCT (whatever that means). Within it there's a Object[] m_objArray  which contains String. At least that's how I'm reading it.  And how can access m_objArray's values?